# Compare elements in a two way table and display uncommon results in r

Tags: r, rstudio

I've a two, two way tables and I'm trying to compare each intersecting element in both the tables and display the uncommon cell.
For instance

Table 1 has the following data

```
COURSE   Jan'16   Jan'15   Feb'16    Feb'15    Mar'16      Mar'15
Animal      403    1061     313       122      -281        -130
Anti       28990   11035    6411     5589      -10816      -1233
```

and table 2 has

```
COURSE   Jan'16   Jan'15   Feb'16    Feb'15    Mar'16      Mar'15
Animal      403    1061     313       122      -281        -130
Anti       28990   11035    6411     5589      -10816      -1003
```

So I'm trying to compare the tables such that the final output would be

```
COURSE   Jan'16   Jan'15   Feb'16    Feb'15    Mar'16      Mar'15
Anti      NA          NA      NA        NA        NA       -1003
```

and the output would also contain entries which aren't there in either of the tables

I tried using `anti_join` function from `dplyr` but  it would compare the whole row and give out the uncommon result.

Is there any other function or package similar to that of `anti_join` for two way tables that would work in my case?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it what you mean?

```
table2[table2==table1] <- NA
```

Comment: I guess this function won't work as the number of observations in both the tables are different

Comment: Then what do you mean by comparing them?

Comment: By comparing, I mean a cell by cell comparison say for instance, Animal - Jan'16 from table 1 compared with animal- Jan '16 of table 2 and so on